# How can Wolverine bend his wrists?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine

Wolverine's claws are clearly longer than his hands. That being the case, shouldn't they retract into his forearms and prevent his wrists from bending?

Comment: Because the claws retract into the upper part of his forearm; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLiNyglOyJY

Comment: So he can't bend his wrists with claws _extended_?

Comment: presumably he can because most of the claw is out of his hand